# Update database EF Core Azure build step

Tags: azure, entity-framework-core, azure-pipelines-build-task

I've defined steps to build and run tests for my ASP.NET Core MVC app and it all works fine.

Now I want to add a step that actually runs the migrations (if any) and that step to works (it doesn' fail :). Allthough I can't understand why it works since it probably uses the setting from appsettings.json, which don't have any connection strings, they're defined in user secrets.

So my question is: Is there any easy way to get the connection string defined in the App Service for the site I want to build?

A neat option would be to define a variable with the same name, e.g `ConnectionStrings:db` that check if there is any app setting with the specified key in the Azure portal and then use it.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The better way is using [Azure Key Vault](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/key-vault-whatis). You can refer to this blog for detail steps of [protecting secrets using VSTS and azure key value](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/najib/2017/03/07/protecting-secrets-using-vsts-and-azure-key-vault/).

Another way is that you can use secure variable in build/release, and replace the specified value in appsettings.json by using **JSON vairble substitution** of **Azure App Service Deploy task**. (match the key, so appsettings.json file should contain connectionstring key).

Comment: How would using Deploy task work in conjunction with dito defined in the Release configuration? Doesn't feel correct to execute that during the build and test phase. I guess that's the reason for Releaes - to separate the two

Comment: @joacar Not clear it, you can provide a detail scenario to explain it.

Comment: I have a development build procedure in which I want to apply EF migrations. But I don't want to include the connection string in source control, so I need to get it from somewhere else. Once that problem is solved, the next problem is to make `dotnet ef database update` (or context) aware of the connection string (currently null exception thrown). So how do I get the connection string "in" before the build phase?

Comment: Guess I can either manipulate `appsettings` directly, but then I would need to restore it so the final build doesn't include the file. Better would be that the program can read the variables as environment variables. Then I could just name something like `ASPNETCORE_ConnectionString:Database` and then EF tooling could pick that up